# Drivers for Brother MFC L2740DW

Tags: 18.04, printing

Fairly new to Ubuntu, back from 6.1 version 5 years ago. I am now using Ubuntu 18.04, I am installing the drivers for my Brother MFC l2740DW from the terminal, I already printed a test page and try to scan on the simple scan utility, I am anyway stuck in the terminal to this message and I do not know how to handle it form here:

```
dpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package brscan-skey.
(Reading database ... 164123 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb ...
Unpacking brscan-skey (0.2.4-1) ...
Setting up brscan-skey (0.2.4-1) ...
apt-get install libusb-0.1-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libusb-0.1-4
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 173 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 57.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libusb-0.1-4 amd64 2:0.1.12-31 [17.1 kB]
Fetched 17.1 kB in 1s (32.4 kB/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package libusb-0.1-4:amd64.
(Reading database ... 164129 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libusb-0.1-4_2%3a0.1.12-31_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libusb-0.1-4:amd64 (2:0.1.12-31) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libusb-0.1-4:amd64 (2:0.1.12-31) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
 enter IP address ->192.168.1.73

brsaneconfig4 -a name=MFC-L2740DW model=MFC-L2740DW ip=192.168.1.73
root@giuliano-HP-Compaq-dc7900-Small-Form-Factor:/home/giuliano/Downloads# 
root@giuliano-HP-Compaq-dc7900-Small-Form-Factor:/home/giuliano/Downloads#
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You must follow [pre-required procedure](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=ca&lang=en&prod=mfcl2740dw_us_eu_as&faqid=faq00100548_000) before install. After pre-install over, you must download two deb package `Scanner driver 64bit` and `Scan-key-tool 64bit` for [Brother MFC L2740DW printer](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=ca&lang=en&prod=mfcl2740dw_us_eu_as&os=128) and install them.

Comment: After the drivers for the printer I installed: dpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb and I thought it was done as far as drivers for the scanner but I got a prompt for the ip address of the printer, I input the IP address and the following prompt was: enter IP address ->192.168.1.73

brsaneconfig4 -a name=MFC-L2740DW model=MFC-L2740DW ip=192.168.1.73
root@giuliano-HP-Compaq-dc7900-Small-Form-Factor:/home/giuliano/Downloads# 
root@giuliano-HP-Compaq-dc7900-Small-Form-Factor:/home/giuliano/Downloads#                                                            
Please help!

Comment: @GiulianoC, I suggest following the "pre-required procedures" from Brother's support site that @Marmayogi commented above.  These instructions are straight from the manufacturer for this specific model printer and were last updated in January of this year so they should work.  You may need to `sudo apt purge packagename` for all printer packages that you've already installed and reboot ahead: Since Brother has called these steps "pre-required procedures", it suggests that if you install them out of order, it will not work.

Comment: @GiulianoC, use command `sudo dpkg  -l  |  grep  -i Brother` to know about the driver packages installed in your system and then go ahead and purge them away. Then you follow the contents of my earlier comment to finish the installation. Good Luck!